# DataTables trying to access datatables.net.js with RequireJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, requirejs, datatables, datatables-1.10

I'm trying to configure DataTables to work with RequireJS and my configuration always results in this error:

```
require.js:1926 GET https://preview.c9users.io/{username}/{workspace}/lib/datatables.net.js
Uncaught Error: Script error for: datatables.net
```

My `lib/DataTables/*` (incl. all modules) and `lib/requirejs.js` both need to be stored locally in the folder `lib`, so I don't understand why it is trying to access the file `datatables.net.js`, as no such string is mentioned in any of the config files.

JSFiddle (edited for the purpose of JSFiddle): http://jsfiddle.net/42ucpwee/1/

Is my configuration wrong or what may be the cause of the error?

script.js:

```
define(['jquery','datatables'], function($) {
    $('#example').DataTable();
});
```

main.js:

```
requirejs.config({
    //appDir: "../",
    baseUrl: "lib",
    paths: {
        'jquery': '//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min',
        'bootstrap': '//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min',
        /* Error is the same, I can't even use this CDN URL (I need the editor) 
        'datatables': 'https://cdn.datatables.net/s/bs-3.3.5/jszip-2.5.0,pdfmake-0.1.18,dt-1.10.10,af-2.1.0,b-1.1.0,b-colvis-1.1.0,b-flash-1.1.0,b-html5-1.1.0,b-print-1.1.0,cr-1.3.0,fc-3.2.0,fh-3.1.0,kt-2.1.0,r-2.0.0,rr-1.1.0,sc-1.4.0,se-1.1.0/datatables.min',
        */
        'datatables': 'DataTables/datatables',//'DataTables/datatables.min' exactly same error
        'script': '../js/script'
    },
    shim: {
        'bootstrap': {
            deps: ['jquery']
        },
        'jquery': {
            exports: '$'
        },
        'datatables': {
            deps: ['bootstrap','jquery']
        },
        'script': {
            deps: ['jquery','datatables']
        }
    }
});
requirejs(['script']);
```

index.html:

```
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/s/bs-3.3.5/jszip-2.5.0,pdfmake-0.1.18,dt-1.10.10,af-2.1.0,b-1.1.0,b-colvis-1.1.0,b-flash-1.1.0,b-html5-1.1.0,b-print-1.1.0,cr-1.3.0,fc-3.2.0,fh-3.1.0,kt-2.1.0,r-2.0.0,rr-1.1.0,sc-1.4.0,se-1.1.0/datatables.min.css" type="text/css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/require.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/main.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <table id="example" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Position</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
                <td>System Architect</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

It seems to have moved me a bit forward, now I'm having `datatables.js:93165 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'defaults' of undefined`.

Link to question: [DataTables+RequireJS: Cannot read property 'defaults' of undefined][1]

Some modules worked the way you described some didn't, maybe it's also about the order in which they are imported. Here is the full order as described on their website:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Bootstrap-3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="DataTables-1.10.10/css/dataTables.bootstrap.min.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="AutoFill-2.1.0/css/autoFill.bootstrap.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Buttons-1.1.0/css/buttons.bootstrap.min.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ColReorder-1.3.0/css/colReorder.bootstrap.min.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Editor-1.5.2/css/editor.bootstrap.min.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="FixedColumns-3.2.0/css/fixedColumns.bootstrap.min.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="FixedHeader-3.1.0/css/fixedHeader.bootstrap.min.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="KeyTable-2.1.0/css/keyTable.bootstrap.min.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Responsive-2.0.0/css/responsive.bootstrap.min.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="RowReorder-1.1.0/css/rowReorder.bootstrap.min.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Scroller-1.4.0/css/scroller.bootstrap.min.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Select-1.1.0/css/select.bootstrap.min.css"/>

<script type="text/javascript" src="jQuery-2.1.4/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Bootstrap-3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="JSZip-2.5.0/jszip.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="pdfmake-0.1.18/build/pdfmake.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="pdfmake-0.1.18/build/vfs_fonts.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="DataTables-1.10.10/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="DataTables-1.10.10/js/dataTables.bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="AutoFill-2.1.0/js/dataTables.autoFill.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="AutoFill-2.1.0/js/autoFill.bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Buttons-1.1.0/js/dataTables.buttons.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Buttons-1.1.0/js/buttons.bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Buttons-1.1.0/js/buttons.colVis.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Buttons-1.1.0/js/buttons.flash.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Buttons-1.1.0/js/buttons.html5.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Buttons-1.1.0/js/buttons.print.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="ColReorder-1.3.0/js/dataTables.colReorder.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Editor-1.5.2/js/dataTables.editor.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Editor-1.5.2/js/editor.bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="FixedColumns-3.2.0/js/dataTables.fixedColumns.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="FixedHeader-3.1.0/js/dataTables.fixedHeader.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="KeyTable-2.1.0/js/dataTables.keyTable.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Responsive-2.0.0/js/dataTables.responsive.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Responsive-2.0.0/js/responsive.bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="RowReorder-1.1.0/js/dataTables.rowReorder.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Scroller-1.4.0/js/dataTables.scroller.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Select-1.1.0/js/dataTables.select.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Changed `'datatables'` to `'datatables.net'`, to satisfy the naming requirements in DataTables own scripts: `define( ['jquery', 'datatables.net'], function ( $ ) { ...`. I'm trying to put together a config file for RequireJS and my newest version looks like this:

```
requirejs.config({
    paths: {
        'jquery': '//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min',
        'jquery-ui': '//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui',
        'bootstrap': '//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min',

        //DataTables core
        'datatables' : 'DataTables/datatables.min',
        'datatables.net' : 'DataTables/DataTables-1.10.10/js/jquery.dataTables.min',
        'datatables.net-bs' : 'DataTables/DataTables-1.10.10/js/dataTables.bootstrap.min',

        //Dependencies
        'datatables.net-autofill' : 'DataTables/AutoFill-2.1.0/js/dataTables.autoFill.min',
        'datatables.net-editor' : "DataTables/Editor-1.5.2/js/dataTables.editor.min",
        'datatables-editor-bootstrap' : "DataTables/Editor-1.5.2/js/editor.bootstrap.min",
        'datatables.net-buttons' : 'DataTables/Buttons-1.1.0/js/dataTables.buttons.min',
        //'datatables.net-buttons' : 'DataTables/Buttons-1.1.0/js/buttons.bootstrap.min',

        //Extra modules
        'datatables.net-buttons-bs' : 'DataTables/Buttons-1.1.0/js/buttons.bootstrap.min',
        'datatables.net-colreorder' : "DataTables/ColReorder-1.3.0/js/dataTables.colReorder.min",
        'datatables.net-rowreorder' : "DataTables/RowReorder-1.1.0/js/dataTables.rowReorder.min",
        'datatables.net-scroller' : "DataTables/Scroller-1.4.0/js/dataTables.scroller.min",
        'datatables.net-select' : "DataTables/Select-1.1.0/js/dataTables.select.min",

        //some modules are still missing from the full package...
    },
    shim: {
        'jquery' : {
            exports : 'jquery'
        },
        'bootstrap' : {
            deps : [ 'jquery' ],
            exports : 'Bootstrap'
        },
        'datatables' : {
            deps: ['jquery','bootstrap']  
        },
        'script': {
            deps: ['datatables','datatables.net-colreorder','datatables.net-rowreorder','datatables.net-scroller','datatables.net-select']
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: There is no `datatables.min.js` in DataTables 1.10.10. So the following line in `paths` does not seem right: `'datatables' : 'DataTables/datatables.min',`. Also, it is not correct to have `shim` for modules that call `define`. jQuery calls define. So no `shim` for it.

Comment: Thank you so much Peter. This was the final solution to so many hours of struggling for me

Answer (score 17):

I solved the problem, like this:

```
    require.config({

    baseUrl: "/MyFrontEnd/resource",

    paths: {
        "jquery": "js/jquery-2.1.4.min",
        "datatables.net": "DataTables-1.10.10/media/js/jquery.dataTables.min",
        "datatables" : "DataTables-1.10.10/media/js/dataTables.bootstrap.min"
        "datatables_select": "DataTables-1.10.10/extensions/Select/js/dataTables.select.min"
    }
});
```

And the HTML page:

```
<script src="../resource`enter code here`/js/require.js"></script>
<script>
require(['/MyFrontEnd/resource/myjs/main.js'], function (main) {
    require(['jquery', 'datatables', 'datatables_select'], function ($, datatables, datatables_select) {
        $(document).ready(function () {
            var table = $('#demo_select').DataTable();
            $('#demo_select').on('click', 'tbody tr', function () {
                if (table.row(this, {selected: true}).any()) {
                    table.row(this).deselect();
                }
                else {
                    table.row(this).select();
                }

                console.log(table.row(this).data());
            });

        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Interesting how you made it work, it also worked for me. I was expecting the solution to be like to set the path to the root `datatables.min.js` in the root `DataTables` folder. There are `RequireJS` dependencies in that file `'datatables', 'datatables.net', 'datatables.net-bs', 'datatables.net-autofill', 'datatables.net-editor', 'datatables-editor-bootstrap', 'datatables.net-buttons'`. But the main thing is that it works!

Answer (score 15):

It worked for me to register the ".net" module names as aliases under the shim config map property:

```
require.config({
    paths: {
      jquery: '../libs/jquery-2.2.4',
      dataTables: '../libs/dataTables/jquery.dataTables-1.10.12',
      dataTables_buttons: '../libs/dataTables/dataTables.buttons-1.2.2'
    },
    shim: {
      dataTables: {
        deps: ['jquery']
      },
      dataTables_buttons: {
        deps: ['dataTables']
      }
    },
    map: {
      '*': {
        'datatables.net': 'dataTables',
        'datatables.net-buttons': 'dataTables_buttons'
      }
    }
});
```

Comment: This worked for me, too. The layout and syntax _feels_ right. By that, I mean using the `map` property seemed the appropriate way to proceed.